# How to use Request::factory()->execute() to call an script from another library in the same host

Tags: php, request, kohana, kohana-3.2

I'm using Kohana 3.2, and I want to be able to call another script (unrelated to Kohana, outside of its 'jurisdiction') that returns a `application/json` response.
When I tried using:

```php
$response = json_decode(Request::factory('/scripts/index.php?id=json')->execute()->body());
```

It errors out saying there's no route to `scripts/index.php`. So I tried using `Request_Client_External`

```php
Request_Client_External::factory()->execute(Request::factory('/scripts/index.php?page=s'))->body();
```

Gives me `Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Error fetching remote /scripts/index.php?page=s [ status 0 ] Could not resolve host: scripts; Host not found`. It appears it need a full flagged URL using http/https, but how to avoid the overhead of it doing a real external request?

Doing a

```
Request::factory(url::site('/scripts/index.php?page=s', 'http'))->execute()
```

works but is it considered "external"?

Comment: To answer you last question - yes, it will be considered an external request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that the only way to use `Request::factory()->execute()` to achieve that is to use pass it the full url (with whatever "overhead" that entails, which shouldn't be too much: your server's probably quite good at talking to itself).

Otherwise, ideally you'd put the functionality of `scripts` into a library and call that from Kohana.  However it sounds like that's not an option for you.  If you have to leave `/scripts/index.php` untouched and **insist** on an 'internal' request, you could use [PHP's output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), as illustrated below.  But there are a bunch of caveats so I wouldn't recommend it: the best way is passing a full url.

```
    // Go one level deeper into output buffering
    ob_start();

    // Mimic your query string ?id=json (see first caveat below)
    $_GET = $_REQUEST = array('id' => 'json');
    // Get rid of $_POST and $_FILES
    $_POST = $_FILES = array();

    // Read the file's contents as $json
    include('/scripts/index.php');
    $json = ob_get_clean();

    $response = json_decode($json);
```

Some caveats.

Firstly, the code changes `$_GLOBALS`.  You probably don't use these in your Kohana code (you use `$this->request->get()` like a good HMVCer, right?).  But in case you do, you should 'remember' and then restore the values, putting `$old_globals = $GLOBALS;` etc. before the above code, and `$GLOBALS = $old_globals;` after.

Sessions: if your `/scripts/index.php` uses `session_start() this will cause a warning if you've already started a session at this point in Kohana.

Note that all variables set in `scripts/index.php` will remain set in the context you're in.  If you want to avoid possible conflicts with that context, you'd start a new context, i.e. wrap the above into its own function.

Finally, you'd also need to make sure that `/scripts/index.php` doesn't do anything like `Kohana::base_url = 'something_else'`, or touch any other static attributes, or do something catastrophic [using this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php).

Comment: good explanation, but I guess I'll just stick the the `Request::factory(url::site('/scripts/index.php','http'))` and let the host do it via HTTP anyway. just a shame I can't call that folder without making an extra HTTP call

Comment: Sounds wise!  If your aim is to avoid making an HTTP request (why?), I just thought: you could use `exec` to start a new (CLI) instance of PHP, like this: `$response = json_decode(exec("php -r '\$_SESSION = json_decode('\''".json_encode($_SESSION)."'\'', TRUE); \$_REQUEST[\"id\"] = \$_GET[\"id\"] = \"json\"; include(\"/scripts/index.php\");'"));`.  You might want to pass `$_COOKIE` the same way I've passed `$_SESSION`.  But yeah, an HTTP request is the way to go.